# process multiple jason arrays from a .dat file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am new to json data processing and stuck with this issue. Data in my input file looks like this -

```
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}] [{"key3":"value3"},{"key4":"value4"}]
```

I tried to read using

```
json.load(file)
```

or by

```
with open(file) as f:
 json.loads(f)
```

tried with `pandas.read_json(file, orient="records")` as well

each of these attempts failed with stating `Extra data: line 1 column n (char n)` issue

Can someone guide how best to parse this file? I am not in favor writing a manual parser which may fail to scale later

P.S. There is no `,` between two arrays
TIA

Comment: You seem to have named a variable `file` which does not make it a file from which you can read with `open`. This is still a text variable.

Comment: that was to show what my file contains.. will rectify it

Comment: `json.load` will take file pointer input, and `json.loads` will take a string as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json file content has issue.

***1. If `,` between arrays:***

Code:

```
import json

with open("my.json") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)  # data = json.loads(fp.read())

print data
```

your file content can be eithor of these.

Option1:
Use outer most square bracket for your json content.

> [[ {"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}], [{"key3":"value3"},
>   {"key4":"value4"}]]

Option2:
use only one square bracket.

> [ {"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}, {"key3":"value3"},
>   {"key4":"value4"}]

***2. If no `,` between arrays:***

code:
Just writing as per the given JSON format.

```
def valid_json_creator(given):
    replaced = given.replace("}] [{", "}],[{")
    return "[" + replaced + "]"


def read_json():
    with open("data.txt") as fp:
        data = fp.read()
    valid_json = valid_json_creator(data)
    jobj = json.loads(valid_json)
    print(jobj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_json()
```

This code works for JSON if it is in the following format.

**Note** no `,` between arrays, but space is there.

> [{"key0":"value0"},{"key1":"value41"}]
>   [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value42"}]
>   [{"key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value43"}]
>   [{"key3":"value3"},{"key4":"value44"}]
>   [{"key4":"value4"},{"key5":"value45"}]
>   [{"key5":"value5"},{"key6":"value46"}]
>   [{"key6":"value6"},{"key7":"value47"}]
>   [{"key7":"value7"},{"key8":"value48"}]
>   [{"key8":"value8"},{"key9":"value49"}]
>   [{"key9":"value9"},{"key10":"value410"}]
>   [{"key10":"value10"},{"key11":"value411"}]
>   [{"key11":"value11"},{"key12":"value412"}]
>   [{"key12":"value12"},{"key13":"value413"}]
>   [{"key13":"value13"},{"key14":"value414"}]
>   [{"key14":"value14"},{"key15":"value415"}]
>   [{"key15":"value15"},{"key16":"value416"}]
>   [{"key16":"value16"},{"key17":"value417"}]
>   [{"key17":"value17"},{"key18":"value418"}]
>   [{"key18":"value18"},{"key19":"value419"}]
>   [{"key19":"value19"},{"key20":"value420"}]

Comment: please note there is no `,` between arrays

Comment: Ohh..! that's again another good point. :) thanks for pointing me.

Comment: @CARTman: do you want the file to be in the same format without a comma in between arrays?

Answer (score 0):

What you have tested is reading from a structure that **corresponds to** the JSON file (which by definition is text, not Python data structure).

Test:

```
file = '[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}],[{"key3":"value3"},{"key4":"value4"}]'
```

This should work better. But wait... you do not seem to provide a list or dict at the top level of your to-be JSON! Hence the error:

> ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 38 - line 1 column 76 (char 37 -
>   75)

Change it then to (note the additional list opening and closing brackets at the beginning and end):

```
file = '[[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}],[{"key3":"value3"},{"key4":"value4"}]]'
```

This will work with:

```
json.load(file)
```

but **not** with:

```
with open(file) as f:
 json.loads(f)
```

as your **text variable** is not a *file*! You would want to store the contents of the variable named `file` to a file and pass the path to that file:

```
with open(r'C:\temp\myfile.json') as f:
 json.loads(f)
```

For the code to work properly.

Comment: I edited my file to put `[ ]` as outermost bracket, still getting this error ``Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)``

Comment: Please note there is no `,` between arrays